# laravel function which loops all duplicate project_id's and only shows last created on show.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel

hello i have a difficult function i need to solve:

i need a function which filters out the projects with the same project_id and only takes the project with the latest created_at data.

i currently have nothing because i dont know where to start but i am pretty sure i need to write it in my index function of my ProjectController.

**overzicht.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="well">
            <div class="card mt-5 mb-5">
                    <h2 class="card-header">{{$projectitem->project_name}></h2>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h2 class="card-text mt-4 mb-2"><b>Beschrijving:</b></h2><br>
                      {!!$projectitem->description!!}

                      <h2 class="mt-4 mb-2"><b>Tijdsduur(in uren):</b>&nbsp;{{$projectitem->time_span}} Uren</h2><br>

                      <h2 class="mt-2 mb-2"><b>Opdrachtgever:</b> &nbsp;{{$projectitem->client}}</h2>

                      <h2 class="mt-4 mb-2"><b>Text verslag:</b></h2><br>
                        {!!$projectitem->text_report!!}

                      <h2 class="mt-4 mb-2"><b>Foto's vooraf: &nbsp;</b></h2><br>
                        {!!$projectitem->images_before!!}
                        <h2 class="mt-4 mb-2"><b>Foto's achteraf: &nbsp;</b></h2><br>
                        {!!$projectitem->images_after!!}

                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <h2 class="mt-4"><b>Beschikbaar op: &nbsp;</b></h2>
                                    <h4>Facebook:&nbsp;<?php if($projectitem->facebook == 1){echo "wel";}else{echo "niet";}?></h4>
                                    <h4>Instagram:&nbsp;<?php if($projectitem->instagram == 1){echo "wel";}else{echo "niet";}?></h4>
                                    <h4>Linkedin:&nbsp;<?php if($projectitem->linkedin == 1){echo "wel";}else{echo "niet";}?></h4>
                                    <h4>Website:&nbsp;<?php if($projectitem->website == 1){echo "wel";}else{echo "niet";}?></h4>
                                </div>                   
                        </div>
                      <h4 class="mt-4 mb-2"><b>Aangemaakt door:</b>&nbsp;{{$projectitem->created_by}}</h4><br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <h4 class="mt-4 mb-2 floatl "><b>Aangemaakt op:</b>&nbsp;{{$projectitem->created_at}}</h4><br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">                                    
                                <h4 class="mt-4 mb-2 ml-1 mr-1 floatr "><b>Laatst gewijzigd op:</b>&nbsp;{{$projectitem->updated_at}}</h4><br>
                            </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


@endsection
```

**index function in Project Controller**

```
$projects = Project::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
     $projectitem = Projectitem::all();//->orderBy('created_at')->limit(1)

     return view('overzicht', [
        'projects' => $projects,
        'projectitem' => $projectitem,
    ]);
```

EDIT: screenshot

[image]

all help is appreciated

Comment: Use `distinct()` and `latest()` on your query.

Comment: i have a couple of records with the same id , the reason behind this is i want my projects table to be an archive and i only want to display the latest created record. i will add a screen to the post

Comment: You could try: `Projectitem::where('project_id', $id)->latest()->unique('project_id');`

Comment: Hello peter, i cant use $id because i dont define it anywhere

Comment: Or maybe `Projectitem::all()->latest()->unique('project_id');` then?

Answer (score -1):

i dont know if it can be right for you or not but you might get it with one query

and by the way you dont need to define the project id as you get it from the project object

```
Project::where('project_id', project->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

Comment: This will return him latest single `Project` instance with a specific `project_id` (code you've provided also has syntax error).